# C# Object from PowerShell Object

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a PowerShell project and I've been working with PowerShell v5 classes to create custom types for the output objects. However, due to various failings in the current implementation of these classes I've decided to try out creating the classes in C# instead.

I've run into a problem that I can't quite figure out when creating the class constructors. I'm working with PowerShell's Invoke-RestMethod and this returns objects of type PSCustomObject. I need to use those objects' properties to instantiate objects from C# classes, as well as calculate some additional properties. An example PowerShell constructor looked like this:

```
class user
{
    [string]
    $username

    [string]
    $userprincipalname

    [hashtable]
    $custom_attributes

    static [string] getStatus ([int]$Status)
    {
        { return [UserStatus]([int]$Status)
    }

    static [hashtable] getCustom_Attributes ([PSObject]$custom_attributes)
    {
        $Output = @{}
        $custom_attributes.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
            if ($_.Value) {$Output[$_.Name] = $_.Value}
        }
        return $Output
    }

    User ([PSCustomObject]$InputObject)
    {
        $this.username          = $InputObject.username
        $this.userprincipalname = $InputObject.userprincipalname
        $this.custom_attributes = [User]::getCustom_Attributes($InputObject.custom_attributes)
    }
}
```

Now I've tried something similar in C#, but it doesn't appear that you can reference the constructor parameter properties inside the constructor:

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
namespace test
{    
    public class user 
    {
        public string username {get; set;}
        public string userprincipalname {get; set;}
        public object[] custom_attributes {get; set;}

        static string getStatus (int Status)
        {
            return Enum.GetName(typeof(test.userstatus), Status);
        }

        user (PSCustomObject InputObject)
        {
            this.username          = InputObject.username;
            this.userprincipalname = InputObject.userprincipalname;
            this.custom_attribute  = test.User.getCustom_Attributes(InputObject.custom_attributes);
        }
    }

    public enum userstatus
    {
        Active,
        Inactive
    }
}
```

When I import this with Add-Type I get an error:

'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject' does not contain a definition for 'username' and no extensionmethod 'username' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assemblyreference?)

Am I going about this entirely wrong? How can I create C# objects from the PSCUstomObjects while also having the capability to calculate some additional or replacement properties?
Thanks!

Comment: Is this the actual code? Look at what you have in the constructor

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Thanks, yeah I see what you're referring to. This is similar to the actual code I'm using, but my classes have several other properties as well. Looks like I did a bad copy/paste and included the wrong properties in the constructor. This is fixed in the post above now.  However, this isn't really the issue I'm running into as the actual classes have the correct property names.

Comment: C# and PowerShell are very different languages. In short, C# does not Work That Way and PowerShell's classes are more of an afterthought. The C# equivalent to what PowerShell does with objects is `ExpandoObject` and `dynamic`, but that's probably not what you're looking for. Passing a `Hashtable` to the constructor is more logical.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I agree - I've found PowerShell classes could fill many needs, but they are simply not developed enough to work consistently. That's why I'm attempting to use C# classes with this project. Many folks have been doing this for a while, but I'm still a complete beginner with the language as you can see. And I've realized that C# doesn't work that way, but haven't yet found an example of what I would like to achieve. Do you know of an example of this with `hashtables`? Thanks!

Comment: I know that I could do all of this with constructor parameters, but some of my classes would have 15, 20 or more properties and object instantiation would look awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came around to a simpler solution that I believe meets my needs. Instead of relying on constructors, I'm using custom getters to create my calculated properties:

```
public class User
{
    public string username {get; set;}
    public string userprincipalname {get; set;}
    public string status {get; set;}
    public string status_value
    {
        get
        {
            return Enum.GetName(typeof(UserStatus), Int32.Parse(this.status));
        } 
    }
}
```

So far, this appears to be working, and I've abandoned my constructors entirely and am just using the default constructor. I believe I could still use a constructor with these and get the same result from the getters.

Thanks for your help, all!